# How to use OpenZepplin hooks to cancel transfer if condition is not met?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, solidity-0.7.x

I am experimenting with OpenZepplin Hooks to modify ERC20 transfer functions in this way

```
contract IToken is ERC20 { 
....
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
    internal virtual override
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

    require(amount > 1, "ERC20: invalid transfer amount");
}
```

}

However if set `amount = 0.5 tokens` the transfer is still happening. Any idea what is the right way to make transfer fail if the condition is not met?

Comment: What is the decimal do you token! There is not such a thing as 0.5 token, solidity has no floating number. In normal erc20 1 does not mean 1 token, the tools like metamask just show you “1” based on the decimal of the erc20 so if you have 1 token then the amount is actually not 1 in the smart contract it is 100000.......etc.

Comment: of* your* token!

Comment: @MajdTL Realized that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hooks allow you lots of flexibility in modifying the behaviour of a token by allowing you to execute functionality, in the case of the _beforeTokenTransfer hook, you can execute functionality before the token is transferred.

You could restrict transfer (other than minting) to only registered candidates, you could mint another token to signify that the original holder has voted, you could prevent transfer outside of specific voting times, you could emit a vote event.

If you don’t need to use hooks, then you don’t need to include the function in your child contract.

An example is shown below (though I have only left comments rather than actually do anything in the hook):

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/presets/ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId {
    constructor()
        public
        ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId(
            "My Token",
            "TKN",
            "https://example.com/api/token/"
        )
    {}

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override(ERC721, ERC721Pausable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

        // do stuff before every transfer
        // e.g. check that vote (other than when minted) 
        // being transferred to registered candidate
    }
}
```